# Foxpro2 in Windows XP VPC "Too many open files"

Tags: windows-xp, dos, foxpro, vpc

I am converting an old Foxpro2 DOS app and for reference I have the foxpro app running in a Windows XP VPC. Certain application flows cause a `Too many files open` error. Any ideas on how to resolve this? I have tried adding `FILES=200` in config.sys as suggested in one blog post but that doesn't work, maybe because this a virtual PC.

Comment: I'd think you'd need the FILES=200 in the config.sys for the virtual machine, not the actual computer.

Comment: I did edit the VM's config.sys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to remember that the Windows\System32\config.nt file should contain the settings for FILES= and BUFFERS= on WinNT PCs.